# Remove element on basis of class in Angular 6

Tags: html, css, arrays, typescript, angular6

I have one list in that on click of each item one class is toggle in that list. Here is my code

[My Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smrsp4)

I am toggling class in list. I want to remove unselected element from list when user click on "ADD" button. I have done till toggle class in list but I am facing problem while removing items on basis of css class. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s1xjd5)

```
  deleteNotSelect() {
    let data = this.items.filter(data => data.active == true)
        if (data.length > 0) {
            this.items = data;
         }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @UnluckyAj.. working but the problem is if nothing is selected all are deleting

Comment: Hi @UnluckyAj what should I do if I want to add removed items on back button. can tou please help me.

Comment: how you are getting the original array. call the same method.

Comment: I am getting array from json object

Comment: call same json object again on different page.

Answer (score 3):

if i understood exactly what you need, that you want to delete the unselected items when clicking the button ADD,
then add this to your button.

```
<button (click)="removeUnSelected()">ADD</button>
```

and add this function to your app.ts file

```
removeUnSelected() {
console.log(this.items[0].active);
// check if enything is selected first
let flag=0;
let i=0;
for(i=0;i<this.items.length;i++) {
  if(this.items[i].active) {
    flag=1;
    break; 
  }
}
if(flag){
for(i=0;i<this.items.length;i++) {
  if(!this.items[i].active) {
    this.items.splice(i, 1); 
    i--; 
  }
}
}
```

}

i tried it already... this will delete the items from the array if they are not selected when clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks @maha working but the problem is if nothing is selected all are deleting.

Comment: u're very welcome .. what do you want to happen if nothing is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Use a forEach loop to toggle false the active propery of the item:

```
  add() {
    this.items.forEach(function(v,i){
        v.active = false;
    })
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptyb4v?file=src/app/app.component.ts)